# Behavior of two gases in a closed container

Tags: pressure, ideal-gas

If two ideal gases with different molecular weights (i.e. nitrogen and argon) are injected into a closed container (of any given size, but assume ~1L), what will happen over time, assuming all external variables are held constant (no movement, no temperature change, no leaks, etc.)?

a) The two gases will mix evenly within the container; or,
b) the two gases will separate, so that the heavier gas is "on the bottom"?

Would the relative volume of the two gases have any effect one way or the other?

Further, assuming the two gases are initially in a "random/agitated" state (as a result of the physical forces of them being injected into the container), how long would it take for them to reach their end-state?

Would it make any difference if the two gases were injected together vs. one gas being present in the container and the second gas being injected afterward, displacing some of the "original" gas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At any temperature $T$ the [equipartition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem) tells us that a molecule in an ideal gas will have a kinetic energy of order $\tfrac{3}{2}kT$. Since kinetic energy is related to velocity by $E = \tfrac{1}{2}mv^2$ we can use this to estimate the velocity of gas molecules at room temperature, and for argon and nitrogen this works out to around 400 to 500 m/s.

So the gas molecules in your container are all whizzing around at hundreds of metres per second, and unsurprisingly this means they mix with each other. The speeds are so high that the different weights of the two types of molecule has essentially no effect in separating them.

Gravity does have an effect, and this is described by the [barometric equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometric_formula#Density_equations):

$$ \frac{\rho}{\rho_0} = \exp\left( \frac{-gM(h - h_0)}{RT} \right) $$

This relates the density $\rho$ to height $h$. $g$ is the gravitational acceleration and $M$ is the molar mass of the gas. Let's take your one litre container, in which case the height of the container is around 10cm, and the molar mass of nitrogen is 0.028kg. If we feed these values into the barometric equation we find the density ratio between the top and bottom of the container at room temperature is:

$$ \frac{\rho}{\rho_0} \approx 0.999989 $$

This is for nitrogen. The molar mass of argon is larger at 0.04kg, but this only reduces the ratio $\rho/\rho_0$ to 0.999984. So although in principle the argon to nitrogen ratio changes slightly from the bottom to the top of you container the change is vanishingly small. In practice the gas composition remains uniform.

If you make your container very large, e.g. about the thickness of Earth's atmosphere, then the change in composition does become measurably large, which is why the composition of Earth's atmosphere does change with height.

The second part of your question is a bit different since it starts with separated gases and asks how quickly they would mix. Given the gas molecules are travelling so fast you might think the mixing would be extremely rapid, but in fact this isn't the case. The trouble is that gas molecules collide with each other and ricochet back in random directions. The average distance a gas molecule travels before hitting another molecule is called the [mean free path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_free_path), and at room temperature and pressure the mean free path is around 0.1 microns.

So even though a nitrogen molecule is moving at about 500 m/s it's moving at random not in a straight line. If you start with two gases separated into different layers then the mixing is surprisingly slow. In fact as discussed in the question [Why is it difficult to mix helium and nitrogen gases?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/188856/why-is-it-difficult-to-mix-helium-and-nitrogen-gases) it can be so slow that it takes days or weeks to happen.

Assuming you aren't stirring the mixture in any way the mixing takes place by diffusion, and will be described by the [diffusion equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_equation).

Comment: Excellent! This question came from a discussion on "argon wine preservers" (you've probably seen these--the idea is that you inject a burst of argon into an opened, half-finished wine bottle in order to create a "blanket" of inert gas on the surface of the wine to prevent contact with the air left in the bottle, thus preventing oxidation). My position, based on everything I've ever learned about gases, is that this concept is completely flawed, in spite of the fact that argon is heavier than oxygen. Your answer (and eyqs') seem to support my position. Based on that extra detail, do you agree?

Comment: Regarding the He/N mixing (which I had found earlier), the conclusion seems to be that the significant difference in density between those particular gases was the root issue with mixing. It seems to me that the differences between Ar, O, and N would be trivial. Any thoughts?

Comment: @eric: I think the idea of the argon wine preservers is that the argon displaces the air so the bottle headspace contains only argon. In principle it is possible to lay down a layer of argon below the air (argon is about 50% denser than air) if you fed the argon in slowly and smoothly, but you'd need to be very careful as any agitation would create currents and mix it up with the air. I suspect that in practice it would be very difficult.

Comment: Re the He/N: the problem is that because the density difference is so great and the viscosity of helium is low it's hard to get the turbulent mixing needed to mix the two. An analogy would be mixing water and treacle. You can do it, but it takes a lot of shaking. Diffusion is (almost) unaffected by density differences and is generally very slow. Unsurprising really when you consider that the mean free path of an air molecule is under a tenth of a micron!

Comment: Thanks for your input John. Yes, I agree that total displacement of the air could be the objective (although I've seen the "blanket of argon" claim by many manufacturers of this kind of product. But even total displacement seems like it would be very difficult without a fairly long purge (and fair amount of argon). Either way (purge or blanket), seems like a few shots of argon from a pressurized can (which is how these things come) would rarely if ever accomplish the intended objective.

Comment: But I'm confused about the ability to "lay down a layer of argon", as you say, even if it's done very carefully. Are you saying that if you could somehow gently introduce the argon into the bottle at the boundary layer between the air and the wine that it would stay put if you didn't agitate the bottle at all? If so, how likely is that (i.e. how much agitation would be needed to cause the two gases to diffuse into each other)?

Comment: @eric: yes. Suppose you placed a tube with it's end right at the wine/air interface and very slowly pumped argon through the tube - so slowly that the flow was laminar. Because Ar is quite a bit denser than air it will form a layer between the wine and the air, and without any turbulence there won't be any currents to mix up the two. Diffusion would eventually mix the gas layers, but the timescale would be hours not seconds. Of course this is a highly artificial setup, and in practice I doubt you could do it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's go back to the kinetic molecular theory of ideal gases. At high temperature and low pressure, we can approximate real gases as being point particles that move in straight lines and collide elastically. Notice that since they move on straight lines, gravity does not affect them!

How can we justify this approximation? Well, when the kinetic energies of particles are as high as they are in a gas—[$1966 m/s$ for an unbonded hydrogen to $419 m/s$ for carbon dioxide](http://www.science.uwaterloo.ca/~cchieh/cact/c120/gaskinetics.html)―the acceleration due to gravity, just $9.8 m/s^2$, is far too small to affect them meaningfully! In fact, there are no considerations in the ideal gas model for gravity, so gases mixing on Earth act approximately the same way as gases mixing out in space.

Another way to think about it is that solids and liquids can sink and float because they have definite densities, and displace a definite volume of whatever they're floating on. On the other hand, you can easily change the density of a gas by compressing it, and they will just expand to fill their entire container anyway! Recall [Dalton's Law of Partial Pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalton%27s_law); all the gases in a container will expand to fill it, since nothing's stopping them from doing so, and the sum of the partial pressure of all those gases is the total pressure on the whole mixture.

So in conclusion, the gases will mix evenly. Otherwise, the atmosphere at sea level would be extremely flammable indeed!

Now to your other questions. These deal with diffusion, and the time it takes for the gases to expand into their final state depend on the types of gases, the speed of injection, and other such factors. You're probably expected to use [Fick's Laws of Diffusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fick%27s_laws_of_diffusion) to calculate these things. The difference between injecting both at the same time and injecting one into the other is that there exists a concentration gradient $\nabla \phi$ when you're injecting a gas from a high density region (your injection pump, or what have you) to a low density region (the empty container), but there is no concentration gradient for the gas that is already in the container, and so you'll have to apply Fick's laws differently.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Excellent information. I'd like to mark yours and John's as the answer, but of course I can only mark one, so I think it will have to go to John based on the additional details on barometric pressure and why a large "container" like the earth can develop gas stratification but a small container like a 1L flask essentially can't. Thank you!

Comment: You're very welcome! I agree that the barometric equation answers your question better, and I learned something new today as well.